# SQL Join table with null data retrive none

Tags: mysql, sql

so my problem is that lets say i have 3 tables: "customerPerAdmin","admins","customers"
and i'm joining them, but what if, customerPerAdmin.AdminID will be 0 for a certain user?
what will happen that it will ignore the customer with adminID equals to zero, and i dont want that to happen, i want to set admins.FirstName and admin.LastName as empty.

customerPerAdmin Table:

```
ID  AdminID CustomerID
40  20     49           
41  25     48        
42  20     50
43  0      51
```

and this is the query

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `customers.UniqID`,
       `customerPerAdmin`.`AdminID`,
       `customerPerAdmin`.`CustomerID`,
       `customerPerAdmin`.`IsDeleted`,
       `customerPerAdmin`.`pr`,
       `admins`.`ID`,
       `admins`.`GroupID`,
       `admins`.`FirstName` AS adminFirstName,
       `admins`.`LastName` AS adminLastName,
       `admins`.`IsDeleted`,
       `customers`.`FirstName`,
       `customers`.`LastName`,
       `customers`.`Phone`,
       `customers`.`Email`,
       `customers`.`GroupID`,
       `customers`.`UniqID`,
       `customers`.`Created`,
       `customers`.`IsDeleted`,
       `customers`.`ID`
FROM (`customers`)
JOIN `customerPerAdmin` ON `customers`.`ID`=`customerPerAdmin`.`CustomerID`
JOIN `admins` ON `admins`.`ID`=`customerPerAdmin`.`AdminID`
AND `customers`.`GroupID` = '8'
AND `customerPerAdmin`.`pr` = 0
GROUP BY `customers`.`ID`
ORDER BY `customers`.`ID` DESC LIMIT 20
```

so what will happen, it will only show me the IDs of 40,41,42 and not 43 because he cant relate it to an admin with ID of 0, because he is not exists.
how can i still show ID 43 even if it not related?

thanks in advance.

Comment: change from `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: thank you so much! that worked!, can you give me more detailed explanation about outer and inner join? because i dont really understand them

Comment: http://clip2net.com/s/72syyq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you need to change from `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

By using `INNER JOIN` you are forcing all rows to be matched. `LEFT OUTER JOIN` lets you get all the rows from your primary table plus all matching records from Joined table(s).

Here is quick and dirty `JOIN` lesson

`INNER JOIN` or `JOIN`
Get Data from tables where all rows are match

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` 
Get data from primary table and only get data from joined table(s) where data can be matched.

`FULL OUTER JOIN` or `FULL JOIN` 
Get data all data from both tables and match what ever possible.

There is also `RIGHT` join but I never use it. It is same as `LEFT` just making another table the primary source. Some people use both `LEFT` and `RIGHT` in the same query, at which point I start to doubt if they know what they are doing.

In addition to link in the comment you can review [Join Fundamentals from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)